# What is the point of the done() callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mocha.js

In Mochajs, they use `done()` to test for asynchronous code, like so:

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

What does this mean exactly? I did `console.log(done.toString())` and I got this:

```
function (err) {
  if (err instanceof Error || toString.call(err) === '[object Error]') {
    return done(err);
  }
  if (err) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(err) === '[object Object]') {
      return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: '
        + JSON.stringify(err)));
    }
    return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: ' + err));
  }
  done();
}
```

Is the `done()` at the very end here different than the `done()` in the first piece of code?

Comment: In the first piece of code `done()` refers to the `done` parameter. In the second piece of code `done()` refers to definition of `done()` found in the current scope.

Comment: The testing framework needs to know when the asynchronous operation is finished so it can check that the test passed.  So it gives you a `done()` function that you call to let it know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mocha is able to handle synchronous and asynchronous tests. When you run a synchronous test, you can just pass it as an anonymous function to `it` and you don't have to do anything else: Mocha knows the test is over when the function returns. However, **if you are running an asynchronous test, you have to tell Mocha that the test is asynchronous.** There are two ways to do this:

1. Declare that the anonymous function you pass to `it` takes a parameter. Mocha will call your anonymous function with a single parameter which is a function you must call to indicate that your test is over. (This parameter is called `done` due to tradition. You could call it `complete`, `cb` or `platypus` and it would work just the same.) If you call `done` without a value, the test is successful. With a value, the test is a failure and the value should be an `Error` object or an object derived from `Error`.
2. Return a promise: Mocha will wait for the promise to be resolved or rejected. If resolved, the test is successful. If rejected, the test failed.

The code you see when you do `done.toString()` is just the code of the function that Mocha passes to your test when you declare it to take a parameter. You can see in it some of what I mentioned above (e.g. if you pass a parameter to `done` it should be an `Error` or derived from `Error`). The `done` in there is another `done` function which is private to Mocha.

Comment: @Luis thank you for this detailed answer! do have an article that explains the whole concept of done() function in the javascript ecosystem, please?

Answer (score 3):

Because of asynchronous nature of node.js, you have to tell to Mocha that your finished test.

For classic synchronous languages, you are done when the method has finished. But in node, first the whole method is executed and then, some time after is executed inner body of `user.save()`.

The Mocha just waits with test until `done()`, is called, because it does not have any other option to find if something else should be executed or it is finished.

The output you have is just body of function `done`.

Answer (score 3):

All test cases including `before()`, `after()`, `beforeEach()`, `afterEach()` must call `done()` at the end to tell Mocha that all tasks are completed.

If `done()` is missing, a timeout exception will be raised because Mocha will wait for `done()` until timeout.

Comment: But why? Sometimes "done" is not included in the function parameter and the test just ends.

Comment: can i see your sample code?

from my experiences,

before(), after(), beforeEach(), afterEach(), it() must have done() at the end

Comment: the callbacks before, after and so on are just like "normal" mocha tests. they can either have a done callback or not. if present in the functions argument list, mocha will timeout if done() is not called, otherwise it just ends after the last function call. One exception is, if your test returns a promise - then mocha will resolve that promise...